# Find a function applied value in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

I have a problem that I've been trying to find the best solution to using the existing Scala collections library, but I can't seem to come up with something.

Given a set of functions, I need to find the first function result for some input that satisfies a predicate. Here's a simple implementation:

```
def findResult[A, B](t: Traversable[Function1[A, B]], value: A, p: B => Boolean): Option[B] = {
  var result: Option[B] = None
  breakable {
    for (e <- t) {
      val r = e(value)
      if (p(r)) { result = Some(r); break }
    }
  }
  result
}


// test
val f1 = (s: String) => if (s == "a") "aa" else null
val f2 = (s: String) => if (s == "b") "bb" else null
val l = List(f1, f2)

findResult(l, "b", (v: Any) => v != null) must equal(Some("bb"))
```

Is there a better way to do this using the Collections API?

Edit: One restriction I'd like to put in place is that each function should only be applied once, since while my example is trivial, my actual usage for this is not. This restriction is what led me to the implementation above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [view](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html):

```
def findResult[A, B](t: Traversable[Function1[A, B]], value: A, p: B => Boolean) = {
  t.view.map(_(value)).find(p(_))
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I wasn't sure if a view would work like that, but I see that it does. Thanks!

Comment: Oh. :) I was working on updating my own answer for so long, I didn't even notice your new answer. I ended up concluding the same.

Answer (score 4):

I was going to just comment on tenshi's answer, but then I decided to expand it into an alternate approach. Note that if you use `map` on a strict Traversable, then the entire list will be mapped *before* any finding occurs. That means you will end up performing a little extra work.

You could instead just use a find:

```
def findResult[A, B](t: Traversable[Function1[A, B]], value: A, p: B => Boolean) =
    t find (fn => p(fn(value)))
```

This will instead return the *function* that satisfies the predicate `p` for `value`. If you instead need the result, you need only apply the function to the value again (assuming the function is referentially transparent). This, of course, will therefore perform a little extra work, but is likely to be slightly less extra work than tenshi's technique. Note that the technique you came up with yourself performs *no* extra work.

[update] If you *really* don't want to perform *any* extra work, then you should use a [collection view](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html). I had to look this up, but I think I've got a handle on it. Now, stealing tenshi's code outright and adding `.view`, here's some copypasta from my interactive session:

```
def f1(x: Int): Int = { println("f1"); x }
f1: (x: Int)Int
def f2(x: Int): Int = { println("f2"); x+1 }
f2: (x: Int)Int
def f3(x: Int): Int = { println("f3"); x+2 }
f3: (x: Int)Int
val fs = List(f1 _, f2 _, f3 _)
fs: List[(Int) => Int] = List(, , )
(fs.view map (f => f(1))) find (_ == 2)
f1
f2
res8: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```

As you can see, f1 and f2 executed, but not f3. This is because once the result of `f2(1)` was found to be `== 2`, the `find` function was able to stop. That's part of the magic of views: lazy mapping. In fact, the `map` and `find` operations are fused together thanks to views! Or so I'm told.

```
def findResult[A, B](t: Traversable[Function1[A, B]], value: A, p: B => Boolean) =
    t.view map (f => f(value)) find p
def even(x: Int) = x % 2 == 0

findResult(fs, 1, even)
f1
f2
res13: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```

So there you have it. One gem I found in the documentation I linked above was this:

> [As of Scala 2.8] All collections except streams and views are strict. The only way to go from a strict to a lazy collection is via the `view` method. The only way to go back is via `force`.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I updated my question to require that each function only be applied once. While my example functions are trivial, in practice they aren't and I hate the idea of applying them twice.

Comment: @Josh: I've updated my answer to address this. I also learned some Scala in the process!

Answer (score 2):

Combination of `map` and `find` should work:

```
def findResult[A, B](t: Traversable[Function1[A, B]], value: A, p: B => Boolean) =
    t map (fn => fn(value)) find p
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I'm sorry I forgot to mention initially - one of the reasons I hit on this problem is because I only want to apply the functions if necessary, short circuiting once the predicate applies. I added this as a restriction to my initial question.